# A question of pits and stomachs

Tags: idioms, american-english

Since around the year 2000, confirmed by [**Ngrams**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pit%20of%20my%20stomach%2Cpit%20in%20my%20stomach&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#), the common phrase "**I felt (dread etc) in the pit of my stomach**" has become somewhat corrupted to "**I had (or felt) a pit in my stomach**". I've seen it several times recently in internet posts and popular fiction.

I doubt there's a 'patient zero' to be found, but I'm curious what might explain why this has become increasingly popular, when before 2000 it was virtually non-existent.

I hope this isn't seen as opinion-based -- I'm looking for a scholarly, or at least informed, reason why this might have arisen.

Comment: You are right, according to https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&corpus=26&content=I+had+a+pit+in%2C+I+felt+a+pit+in+&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20had%20a%20pit%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20felt%20a%20pit%20in%3B%2Cc0 I had/felt a pit in my stomach became common from mid-90s.

Comment: This is clearly the pits.

Comment: I think it's a matter of opinion whether the expression "pit in my stomach" is a legitimate new usage or an error.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Can you supply an authoritative reference to support that?

Comment: *"I had (or felt) a **pit** in my stomach"* is a malapropism. I assume that someone thought that **"pit"** = the stone or large seed of a fruit, or that **"pit"**  = a deep hole, as opposed to the true meaning of **"pit of the stomach** n. *the epigastric fossa, a slight depression below the xiphisternum; (also) the epigastrium or upper abdomen, in which the stomach and solar plexus are located, esp. regarded as the seat of sensations associated with fear, unease"* OED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pit in my stomach" is still controversial, and is considered by some to be an [error](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/30/pit-in-my-stomach/), including Professor Paul Brians, of Washington State University, who has included it in his book "Common Errors in English Usage", alongside such gems as "ad nauseum", and "along the same vein". Mark Liberman, writing on [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3157), traces it as far back as 1980, and calls it an eggcorn.

Comment: What should "*the same vein*" be?

Comment: @RayButterworth - **in** the same vein.

Comment: Ah, right; I was trying in vain to figure out what was wrong with "vein".  ¶ I was going to suggest an edit, but I have too much reputation to do that (it would actually happen without your approval) — such gems as "ad nauseum" (misspelling of "ad nause**a**m"), and "along the same vein" (should be "**in** the same vein").

Comment: @RayButterworth People on this SE's level should be able to find out what is "wrong" with those, if they don't already know, surely?